# JAVA show my own form as a dialog

Tags: java, forms, dialog, jdialog, showdialog

Creating Java application, and have a task:
Need to open new form from my "parent" form, but it should be opened like a dialog
(block "parent" form from editing, while new form is opened)

Tried, to add JDialog component to form, and then show it, but it not "blocks" form from editing, moreover all functionality it suggests to write in the same class as "parent" form.

I would like to have separate class for form, where i can implement, and then only call it from "parent" form.

For example: 
if you have tried C# there is simple way to do this, just create form and then call function, showDialog. So what is the simplest way in JAVA to do this?

//===================================================

**Already find the solution:**

*Extended JDialog

(as I am using netbeans it was easy:
On project package New->Other->swing GUI forms -> DialogForm)

- added one more constructor

  ```
     public ConnectDialog(Window owner,
      Dialog.ModalityType modal) {
  super(owner, modal);
  initComponents();
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(owner);
  ```
- and then called it from my form:

  ```
      ConnectDialog cf = new ConnectDialog(this,Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
  cf.setVisible(true);
  ```

Don't know is it best solution, but for me it is working.

)

Comment: Have you looked at `JOptionPane` (assuming you're using Swing)?  See if the following is of any help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: yes, I have seen, but standard dialogs are not suitable for me.
I want to make dialog like registration (entering some values, some another components, etc..)

Comment: What about **modal** `JDialog` then?  Another link you quite possibly saw already: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html